# Opening a new WPF Window before WaitForExit() without making the window stuck

Tags: c#, wpf, sta

I'm developing a WPF Application. Right now I'm trying to do something like this:

```
          //Print the information about what happened, and open toolbar.
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot find the destination file, The application will now open Google Chrome." + Environment.NewLine
            + "Please fill in the information and when you finish close Google Chrome.");

           //open Attributes Toolbar

            new AttributesToolbar(application.Attributes).Show();

           //start google chrome and wait for the user to close it
            Process.Start(startInfo).WaitForExit();

            var success = (MessageBox.Show("Did you succeed?", "Status check", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes);
            return new RPAResult()
            {
                Succeeded = success
            };
```

These are the steps:

1) After the application could not found a configuration file, it prints a message that the user has to fill in some details himself (That's the background story, not so important).

2) The application opens a toolbar window - that's a WPF Window with some details that the user has to copy and paste from it to the chrome page.

3) The application opens google chrome and waits until the user closed it

The problem is when the "WaitForExit()" command is executed, the entire application is freezed, even the new WPF Window that has just been opened and the user cannot copy and paste anything.

I have tried to open a new thread but it causes a STAThread problem.

Any help please?

Comment: What code have you used to open a new thread and what error are you getting for your "STAThread problem"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start your process in a task and then continue on exit with your message box.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
   Process.Start(startInfo).WaitForExit();
   }).ContinueWith(prevTask =>
   {
   var success = (MessageBox.Show("Did you succeed?", "Status check", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes);
   [...]
   });
```